# jquery animation works one way but not the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this transition to slide sidebar menu in and out. It only seems to work on the first click when it is going from disabled to active. But on the way out it just jumps back to place, with no transition. Any suggestions?

```
if (sideMenu.hasClass('is-disabled')) {
    console.log('working 2');
    sideMenu.removeClass('is-disabled');
    sideMenu.addClass('is-active');
    sideMenu.animate({
        right: "0"
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
else if (sideMenu.hasClass('is-active')){
    console.log('working 3');
    sideMenu.removeClass('is-active');
    sideMenu.addClass('is-disabled');
    sideMenu.animate({
        right: "-300px"
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

Not sure how to replicate in jsfiddle because I am building it on ember.js but here is a link so you can see the js/css/html better

https://jsfiddle.net/stmcxtL2/1/

Comment: Can you post the minimal HTML, CSS, JS to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I added a link to jsfiddle so you can see the code but could not manage to replicate it on jsfiddle

Comment: It seems to work fine in the jsfiddle.

Comment: You can see the side menu on the right slide in and out in jsfiddle? I only see  Menu Bar button but nothing happens on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
   return false;
```

at the end of each if statement

Comment: `event.prventDefault()` would be a better one

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. -_- Stupid mistake.

The is-disabled class had display: none; so it would disappear before effect took place removed the display:none; and problem solved.

Comment: Looking into your code, you also need to use `clearQueue()` to clear previous events or else on quick multiple clicks your code will run animations for each event.